# Erlang distributed - some nodes share 1 app

Tags: shell, erlang, distributed, erlang-otp, gen-server

first of all, I'm sorry about my English, I hope you understand my question.
My project is a distributed game in Erlang, its means that some computers (one node per computer) have to get access to an app. For example, 4 users from 4 computers play in same game, each one see on his screen the same picture like others, so if player 1 make his step, the others see it real time. How I can share the game with other nodes?

if only one computer run the game, I can send commands with message passing to this computer from others and the computer execute the command, but its not the purpose

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 problems you will solving in the future
1. discover other node
2. send message or sync status with another node

here are the suggestions

1. you can set up a center node which keep all clients
2. you send message or sync status with module called `rpc`